# Are strings in Django QueryDicts escaped/safe to use?

Tags: python, django, security, get, escaping

In my code, I need to use a QueryDict that comes from a GET request. Something along the lines of: `<QueryDict: {u'someVariable': [u'someValue']}>`.

Are the strings in `QueryDicts` escaped in any way?

**1)** If I am expecting `someVariable` to an integer as a string, is it safe for me to convert it to an int, or am I required to run it through some sort of sanitization function?

**2)** If `someVariable` is expected to be some string that I want to use as part of a `SQL` query, do I require any sanitization (to protect against SQL injection) before using that string?

Thank you so much for anyone that can help. My lack of knowledge in web security drives me to be extra paranoid about these things because I know how much can go wrong.

Comment: **No.** If it were "escaped" to any particular format (HTML, SQL, JSON, whatever) then it would *not* represent the real data, but a particular encoding of it. So, ***use placeholders for SQL*** (it doesn't matter if this is "expected" to be an integer!) and otherwise use proper escaping techniques at the usage-site.

Comment: (Note: the Django ORM already handles correctly applying parameters internally so no additional "escaping" is required there.)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So in the case of wanting to convert to an integer to use in python rather than to use in a SQL query, would `int(queryDict['someVariable'])` do? or are there django functions that I should use to attempt to parse an int out?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: How PHP has scarred an entire generation...

Comment: @lanzz - Haha I've only used PHP for a small projects. Python is my first language so I might be a younger generation. I just have a healthy fear of treading unfamiliar waters.

Comment: @Landon If data is an integer, then yes, `int` is applicable for the conversion from a string representing to an integer. Even if only used in a query, this should generally be done (even if implicit conversions in SQL may handle it) such that the domain model is correctly represented in code - being consistent will also remove unexpected type-related surprises.